# Setting Raspberry PI eth network to ipv4

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ethernet, raspberry-pi4

I want to connect RPI to wlan0 network, and let the routers DHCP assingn me an IP address. Then I want to connect only one device to ethernet and assign it another IPV4 address using RPI. The problem is, that the device only uses IPV4, and raspberry pi only wants to assign ipv6 addresses on eth0. When I connect the device to a Windows computer it always, automatically get address 169.254.15.70. When I try to send requests to the device via RPI, after connecting it to eth0 they obviously timeout.
I am using RPI 4b rev 1.5 with 22.04 LTS ubuntu server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O40c.png)

I tried both theese techniques:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu

none of which changed anything

actually it did, the second technique just disabled inet at all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXtqF.png)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by using

```
ifconfig eth0 xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Which effectively changed the ip to ipv4. Had to also set it in crontab so it happens every reboot.